# Install Ubuntu 15.04 dual boot Windows 10 on GPT disk with BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Please, help my with a problem. 
I try to install Ubuntu 15.04 (or 14.10, it's not important) dual boot windows 10.
My notebook is Lenovo z570 with BIOS not UEFI and installed windows 10 x64.
When i installed windows 10, she parted disk to GPT, which led to problems with installing Ubuntu.
After Ubuntu install, and reboot, GRUB2 not run, instead this windows boot manager start.

The following description of the disk

```
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D1CB061A-38BF-48CE-BD0D-67E9E1DC0AB2

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1128448   1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1161216 209717247 208556032  99,5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  209717248 945315839 735598592 350,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  945315840 945326079     10240     5M BIOS boot
/dev/sda7  945326080 976773134  31447055    15G Linux filesystem
```

I created BIOS Boot Partition, and tried to reinstall grub (grub-install by chroot to /dev/sda ) but this not work.

Maybe i'm doing something wrong...

Is there a way to intall Ubuntu dual boot Windows 10 at GPT/BIOS ?

Answer (score 1):

You say your machine supports only BIOS, not UEFI. But your partition table shows an EFI system partition (`/dev/sda2`), which never gets created unless an OS was booted via UEFI and tried/succeeded in installing itself.

Further, Windows needs to be coaxed via special methods to install&boot on a GPT disk in a BIOS system, it could not have happened on its own.

Thus its extremely likely that your system has UEFI firmware. If so, a BIOS Boot partition cannot help - an EFI bootloader needs to be added to `/dev/sda2`.

Refer http://www.rojtberg.net/1032/converting-a-ubuntu-and-windows-dual-boot-installation-to-uefi/ from "Enter a Ubuntu chroot" onwards for instructions to do this. Essentially :

- Boot into an Ubuntu disk
- Chroot into your Ubuntu installation on disk
- Install GRUB EFI packages
- Add your .efi bootloader file in your UEFI boot settings

Let me know if you are stuck at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Which Bios? If you are using SeaBIOS, which I believe is the native bootloader for Windows, you can download Ubuntu from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/15.04/ and dowload the old release from there. to an at least 4 gigabyte memory stick